# English version of Ubuntu with Italian keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to install Ubuntu in ENGLISH (UK) but I have an ITALIAN keyboard, which has a different layout to the English keyboard.
How can I install Ubuntu in English but select an Italian layout for the keyboard.
I tried, but it would only allow me to select an English keyboard.
Thanks

Comment: You can select any keyborad layout after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

#### While installing

In case you had selected "install Ubuntu" from the menu when booting, or after choosing to install Ubuntu from a live session you will have a choice to select your keyboard layout from below menu:

[image]

#### On a live session

A live session loads an English keyboard layout by default. This can be changed by clicking on the `En` icon in the top panel to select *Text Entry setting...*. On the next window click on the small <kbd>+</kbd> icon on the bottom left. Then the following box will open:

[image]

Choose your keyboard layout to add it to the list. To remove a layout press the <kbd>-</kbd> icon after selecting.

We can then choose from all layouts we had installed:

[image]