# Can I install a German version of 16.04 in English?

Tags: input-language, system-language

I'm looking to upgrade from 13.10 to 16.04 LTS, and it seems the easiest way is to install it fresh, rather than 2 or 3 upgrades to reach 16.04. This is not a problem as I haven't really anything I want to keep, so losing files is OK. I live in Germany so I can buy a German version now quite cheap, and I can go through the install process in German, but I want that UBUNTU itself and all applications are installed in English. Is this possible? I am a total newbie so downloading, unpacking and installing the version I need is a daunting, and presumably time consuming, task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding upgrading vs reinstalling: you would have to upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 - and then from 14.04 to 16.04. So basically its 2 major upgrade-runs

Comment: Regarding buying a version - you lost me here - just download the iso and burn it - no need to buy an Ubuntu install medium

Comment: Regarding languages - you can always change languages afterwards as well - but i don't understand what you are looking / asking for. It seems like you do want to stick with an english Ubuntu - and just the install process should be in german or am i misinterpreting you?

Comment: If someone else than Canonical is selling Ubuntu, you should not buy there.   @dufte is right regarding "just download the iso", unless you really don't have the bandwidth (and you live in Germany, you almost certainly have the bandwidth)
However, if you are willing to support Ubuntu, as I have done many times, make a donation to Canonical: https://community.ubuntu.com/help-information/funding/ or buy merchandise.  While the OS is free, it still costs money to develop and organize.

Comment: Languages can be set in the "Language Support" application.  It is totally free and easy to use.  You can even have some users using German and other using English on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike with Windows there is no localized version of Ubuntu. With the default installation media as freely available for download from [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) we have an almost exhaustive list of languages supported. On choosing *English* (which is default) we will install Ubuntu and all applications in English.

We still may need to take care to choose an [appropriate keyboard layout](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696791/english-version-of-ubuntu-with-italian-keyboard). You will be asked for your keyboard while installing.

All language settings can be changed later at all time. We may even [start single applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246547/is-it-possible-to-change-language-for-user-interface-temporarily) with a locale different to the system if this was needed.